# Steuer klasse change when my wife working in other country in EU

Tags: taxes, tax-deduction, european-union, germany, bulgaria

Does somebody know how I can change my "Steuerklasse" from 1 to 3 in case my wife works in another country in EU ( Bulgaria). Our daughter leaves also in Bulgaria.
She works for a French international company pays all taxes, etc.

I know it is possible but can't find the right regulation in German tax law.

Thanks in advance to those who can help

Cheers